# Windows Vista update - does it erase disk?

Tags: windows-update

I have windows vista and I want to update it to Windows 7. Does this process clean everything I have on my disk (including Vista) and install new Windows 7 ?

Answer (score 3):

If you install Windows 7 over a current installation without formatting the hdd and without deleting your old partition, then the setup will move your files to C:\Windows.old.

Comment: And if I delete this folder with old Windows nothing wrong will happen? I just want to have clean new Windows installation.

Comment: The folder is just a backup, you can safely delete it, but if you want a clean installation and delete those files anyway, why don't you format the hdd?

Comment: I have this Windows Vista as Hidden Rescue Partition. If I delete this old Windows files I do not lose my Partition. I want to have all the time this Vista rescue , that when I want to re install Windows 7 I install Vista from rescue and update it to Windows 7

Comment: If you have more then one partition, the windows 7 setup will not affect any other partitions except the one you install the system on. There is no way to upgrade Windows vista to 7, you always need a fresh installation, thus I do not really get what you want to do regarding to your last sentence.